# How to run script when ethernet cable is connected

Tags: networking

I have a simple script at `/etc/network/if-up.d/test` containing the following line

```
date >> /var/log/testing.log
```

Running that script manually works fine.  However, rebooting the system runs it twice.  And disconnecting/reconnecting the ethernet cable does not run it at all.  How can I make it work in all 3 scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

It is being run twice at startup because it is running for both the loopback (lo) and ethernet interface(eth0).

Try this in your script.  It should show the interface name.

```
echo $IFACE  >> /var/log/testing.log
```

The man page for ifup has this note:

> Note  that  the  program  does  not run automatically: ifup alone does not bring up interfaces that appear as a result of hardware being installed ...

According to the same man page `ifplugd` may be an option.